# C/GTK updating UI while waiting thread

Tags: c, multithreading, gtk, gtk3

Let's take these example functions:

```
static gboolean
fill (gpointer data)
{
    gtk_progress_bar_pulse (GTK_PROGRESS_BAR (data));

    return TRUE;
}


static void
do_something (struct var *vars)
{
    GtkWidget *dialog, *contentArea;
    gint result;
    dialog = gtk_dialog_new_with_buttons ("pbar",
                     GTK_WINDOW (vars->mainwin),
                     GTK_DIALOG_MODAL | GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT,
                     _("Close"), GTK_RESPONSE_REJECT,
                     NULL);

    contentArea = gtk_dialog_get_content_area (GTK_DIALOG (dialog));
    vars->pBar = gtk_progress_bar_new ();

    gtk_progress_bar_pulse (GTK_PROGRESS_BAR (vars->pBar));

    guint id = g_timeout_add (100, fill, GTK_PROGRESS_BAR (vars->pBar));

    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (contentArea), vars->pBar);
    gtk_widget_show_all (dialog);

    GThread *n = g_thread_new(NULL, do_heavy, vars);

    result = gtk_dialog_run (GTK_DIALOG(dialog));
    switch (result)
    {
        case GTK_RESPONSE_REJECT:
            g_thread_join(n);
            g_source_remove(id);
            gtk_widget_destroy (dialog);
            break;
    }
}
```

when the user click on the *Cancel* button the progess bar update freeze until the thread will finish.
How can i prevent this behavior and updating the UI also when the *Cancel* button is clciked?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to find a way to signal the thread that it needs to interrupt `do_heavy()` before you call `g_thread_join()` on the thread. (`g_thread_join()` simply waits for the thread to finish.)

You can do this in any number of ways with GLib's [multithreading facilities](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.37/glib-Threads.html); for example, a flag variable protected by a mutex.

Comment: can i use `GCancellable` instead of a mutex?

Comment: Even better. Although you may have to check periodically if it's been cancelled instead of relying on the signal, since the signal is emitted in the cancelling thread.

Comment: I searched how to send an end signal to a thread but i found nothing! Gcancellable is not what I'm looking for! Maybe a GCond but I'm not sure...

Comment: You can't end a thread from another thread. You can use `GCond` with `g_cond_timed_wait()`, use a flag variable with `GMutex`, or use `GCancellable` with `g_cancellable_is_cancelled()`, but any way you do it, you have to check periodically during your `do_heavy()` operation whether you should stop and end the thread.